# Flutter BlendMode 'the getter isn't defined'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
background: ShaderMask(
    shaderCallback: (rect) {
      return LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: TextAlignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
      ).createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
    },
    blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
    child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
      placeholder: "assets/placeholder.jpg",
      image: globals.me["avatar"].replaceAll("\\", ""),
    ),
  ),
```

When I debug this code I got this error:

```
The getter 'dstIn' isn't defined for the class 'BlendMode'.
Try importing the library that defines 'dstIn', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'dstIn'.
```

I can't find any solution. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter is not defined as the class is not defined. This error usually appears when you have not imported `dart:ui` (in the case of `BlendMode`).
So make sure that you have the following import at the top of your file:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
```

---

If you are seeing this error for a different class, find out what library the class (or `enum` here) belongs to and import it.

Comment: Not exactly the same problem I was having, but your explanation about the need to manually import the library helped me. Thank you!